# Output Location of `knife cookbook create foo`

Tags: chef-infra

Where does `knife cookbook create <name of cookbook>` create the cookbook?

```
C:\Users\Kevin\cookbooks>knife cookbook create foo
** Creating cookbook foo
** Creating README for cookbook: foo
** Creating CHANGELOG for cookbook: foo
** Creating metadata for cookbook: foo

C:\Users\Kevin\cookbooks>dir

03/24/2014  10:38 AM    <DIR>          .
03/24/2014  10:38 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  57,811,804,160 bytes free
```

I checked `C:\users\kevin\.chef`, but there's no cookbooks there either.

Comment: It varies based on the `cookbook_path` in your `knife.rb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `knife` CLI tool will read and parse the [`knife.rb`](http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_knife.html), specifically the `cookbook_path`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more that 1 knife.rb file.
first write the command

"knife configure"

It will ask question..

Overwrite /root/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb? (Y/N) 
give answer as "n"

So you can get correct location of knife.rb.

So location /root/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb

You can check the cookbook_path in knife.rb file.